# Postgres: longest streak per developer regardless of Saturdays and Sundays

Tags: postgresql

I got the information I needed from my last post about [Postgres: Defining the longest streak (in days) per developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151401/postgres-defining-the-longest-streak-in-days-per-developer).

However now I want know the longest streak per developer regardless of Saturdays or Sundays. For instance, Bob worked from Thursday 18, Friday 19, Monday 22 and Tuesday 23, hence Bob streak is 4 days.

I understand I can use the DOW window function, which gives me 0 as Sunday , 1 Monday and so on. But

I don’t see how I can apply DOW function in the last solution proposed by Gordon Linoff.

Can some of you help me in this matter? Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  working_limits AS (
    SELECT
      MIN(mr_date) AS start_date,
      MAX(mr_date) AS end_date
    FROM
      xxx
  ),
  working_days AS (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS day_number,
      s.d::date AS date
    FROM
      GENERATE_SERIES((SELECT start_date FROM working_limits),
                      (SELECT end_date FROM working_limits),
                      '1 day') AS s(d)
    WHERE
      EXTRACT(dow FROM s.d) BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
  worked_days AS (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS day_number,
      developer,
      mr_date AS date
    FROM
      xxx
    ORDER BY
      developer,
      mr_date
  )
SELECT
  y.developer,
  MAX(y.days)
FROM (
  SELECT
    x.developer,
    COUNT(*) AS days
  FROM (
    SELECT
      wngd.date,
      wd.developer,
      wngd.day_number - wd.day_number AS delta
    FROM
      working_days wngd INNER JOIN worked_days wd
    ON
      wngd.date = wd.date) AS x
  GROUP BY
    x.developer,
    x.delta) AS y
GROUP BY
  y.developer;
```